# Basic exponent question/review

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

I have function $L^2=kL$

If I solve for L, I divide both sides by L and get L=K.

I now have another function $L^A=kL$.
To solve for L, I raise both sides to 1/A, and get $L=\left(KL\right)^{\frac{1}{A}}$.

From the first function, A=2. If I plug A=2 into the second function, I don't get the same answer.

Question: I don't understand why in the first function I can't raise both sides to 1/2, but in the second function I CAN raise both sides to 1/A.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You use $l$ and $L$ interchangeably.  Are they meant to be the same variable?

Comment: (Barring negative values to even roots ...) There's nothing stopping you from raising both sides of either equation to $1/A$. But doing so, even in the second equation, doesn't *solve* for $L$; solving requires having a single $L$ on one side. (Assuming $L\neq0$ and $A\neq1$) What you "really" want to do in that second equation is first divide by $L$ to get $L^{A-1}=k$; then, cancel the power on $L$ by raising both sides to $1/(A-1)$, obtaining $L=k^{1/(A-1)}$. When $A=2$, this matches what happens with the first equation.

Comment: @AndrewChin Yes, sorry! Fixed!

Comment: @blue I cannot believe I made this error. Of course! Thank you thank you! :)